# Why the below join query returns different result?

Tags: sql

1st query - `select * from a full outer join b on a.x = b.y where b.y = 10`

2nd query - `select * from a full outer join b on a.x = b.y and b.y = 10`

Consider these table extensions:

```
 Table a Table b
 ======= =======

 x       y
 -----   -----
 1       2
 5       5
 10      10
```

The first query will return:

```
 10 10
```

And, the second query will return:

```
 1 NULL
 5 NULL
 10 10
```

Could you please let me know the reasons in detail ?

Comment: I couldn't understand why the second query first returns a different results altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query gives the expected result.

But the second query's result is different because you are joining the tables on both the conditions`(a.x = b.y and b.y = 10)`. And since it is outer join, it'll print all the values which satisfy and which are `NULL` and so the output. I created [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc386/2) so that you can understand it better

Answer (score 2):

The second query has condition in the `ON` part so all the records are included even if they don't have pair in the joined table.

The first one has condition in the `WHERE` part so `NULL`s are filtered out.

Comment: There should be a way to choose multiple answers if multiple answers are correct...

Comment: @user2323036 Don't worry. You mentioned it's correct and it's enough:-)

Answer (score 0):

the first has a where clause and so only shows results where it is true (b.y=10)
the join will show all resuts asits a outer join